# How to check map contains values from a list

Tags: apex

Just want to know how can we check whether map contains values from a list

I have a list

```
List<Pickvalues> = new List<Pickvalues>((Pickval1, Pickval2, Pickval3));
```

Now I need to check whether map contains values from above list, I want to check each and every value of list.

Can anyone help me out how to achieve this.

Comment: Checking the map keys or the map values?

Comment: @KeithC map keys only, if map.containskey(list.value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if it contains all values by checking the key set:

```
if(myMap.keySet().containsAll(values)) {
```

Or, you can check if it contains any values:

```
Set<String> testValues = new Set<String>(values);
testValues.retainAll(myMap.keySet());
if(!testValues.isEmpty()) { // Set contains all found values
```

As a final resort, you could also just loop over every item in the list to see if the values is foun:

```
Boolean found = false;
for(String value: values) {
  if(found |= myMap.containsKey(value)) {
    break;
  }
}
if(found) { // Found at least one value
```